# Viber status not shown

Tags: viber-messenger

Why suddenly no status is shown under my Viber contacts names? I did not deactivate the "show status" button, it is still on.

Comment: Try rebooting the phone. Also when internet connection is slow you need to open someones account or message multiple times to show their status. You can also try reinstalling the app.